# Multiplying a list in the values of a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to update the dictionary with i and y. However y only came out as the last list of the variable values

```
multiples_6 = []
multiples_7 = []
multiples_8 = []
multiples_9 = []
multiples_10 = []

for n in range(1,5+1):
  multiples_6.append(6*n)
  multiples_7.append(7*n)
  multiples_8.append(8*n)
  multiples_9.append(9*n)
  multiples_10.append(10*n)

keys = [6,7,8,9,10]
values = [multiples_6,multiples_7,multiples_8,multiples_9,multiples_10]

new_multiples = {}

for i in keys:
  for y in values:
    new_multiples.update({i:y})
```

when i tried this it only gave me the last element in the list of values.

```
Output: {6: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 7: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 8: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 9: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 10: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please revise to describe better what you're trying to do. It doesn't matter that you're new or that you've already researched. Stick to the facts of the problem.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Step through your code and see what each iteration of the loop does. You loop over _all_ keys, and set the value of _every key_ to be _every element_ of the `values` list. Therefore in the last `y` iteration, the value of _every key_ is the _last value_ of `values`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello the comment of @ Pranav Hosangadi says it all. You only should have one loop. You can do this in many formulation in Python. The one I like most is:

```
for key, value in zip(keys, values):
    new_multiples.update({key: value})
```

Comment: Or simply `new_multiples[key] = value`.